# how to create a Form from an object of case class

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using fold method of form as follows

```
def regSubmit = Action { implicit request  =>
    userForm.bindFromRequest.fold({
      formWithErrors=>BadRequest(views.html.Error("Registration failed")( formWithErrors.errors))
    },
    {
      userData=>Ok(views.html.regconf("Registration Successful")(**//here I want to send a Form, not data from the form**))
    })
```

How can I create Form from a tuple or single variable, a class or a case class?

Comment: I used fill method on the userForm. It worked but is it the correct way? My concern is that userForm is earlied with incoming html/http request.Is it safe to reuse it as bindFromRequest might have changed some internal state in it.  `userData=>Ok(views.html.regconf("Registration Successful")(userForm.fill(userData)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userForm` will (usually?) be defined as a `val`, so immutable. It holds the mapping (this field name into a variable in this position of this type, ...) When you use `bindFromRequest.fold` you are not changing `userForm`, you are using the mapping information in `userForm` to generate a new instance of your case class, say `userData` (or a version of the form with errors in it). Each time you execute that method, you will get a new instance of `userData`.

`userForm.fill(userData)` returns a new form instance, a populated instance of the form, so also does not change `userForm` itself.